# Proof verification on my correspondance theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

I am trying to prove a correspondance theorem for rings. Basically it establishes a one to one correspondance between ideals $I$ of $R$ to ideals $I'/I$ of $R/I$.

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Show $b\frac{I'}{I} \subset
>  \frac{I'}{I}$ for all $b \in R/I$, so $b = c + I$ for $c \in R$ and we
>   need to show
>
> $(c + I)\frac{I'}{I} = (c + I)\{ d + I : d \in I' \} \subset I'/I$.
>
> So an element of $(c + I)\frac{I'}{I}$ is $(c + i_1)(d + i_2) = cd +
>  ci_2 + di_1 + i_1i_2$ where $c \in R$ and $d \in I'$. This means
>
> $cd \in cI' \subset I'$ since $I'$ is an ideal of $R$
>
> $ci_2 \in cI \subset I$ since $I$ is an ideal of $R$
>
> $di_1 \in dI \subset I$ since $I$ is an ideal of $I'$ and hence ideal
>   in $R$
>
> $i_1i_2 \in iI \subset I$ since $I$ is of course an ideal of itself.
>
> So now we see that $cd + (di_1 + ci_2 + i_1i_2) \in \{ a + I : a \in
>  I' \} = I'/I$, hence we have shown that  $b\frac{I'}{I} \subset
> > \frac{I'}{I}$. Because $R$ is commutative, the absorption from the
>   right is the same.
>
> Now we show $C = \{ a \in R : a + I \in I^*\}$ is an ideal in $R$,
>   that is we show $bC \subset C$ for every $b \in R$. Here $I^*$ is an
>   ideal in $R/I$, so it takes the form $I^* = \left <  r + I \right >$
>   where $(x + I)I^* \subset I^*$ for all $x + I \in R/I$ where $x \in R$
>
> Let $bc \in bC$, where $c + I \in I^*$, then $bc + bI \in bI^* \subset
>  I^*$, so this means $bc + bI \in I^*$, and there are $i_1, i_2$ such
>   that $bi_1 = i_2$ and so $bc + I \in I^*$ and we prove that $bC
>  \subset C$.
>
> Now we have to show that the correspondence quotient map is bijection.
>   It is already surjective, so we have to show that it is injective.
>
> Now for $a \neq b$, if $q(a) = q(b)$ then $\{ a + I\} = \{ b + I \}$.
>   So this means $a - b \in I$. I need something to prove that $a - b =0$
>    the additive identity and I can't think why $I$ being an ideal of
>   $R$ helps this. I just know that $I = \ker q$, but I don't know what
>   else helps me deduce $\ker q = \{ 0 \}$.
>
> I feel like I made this proof longer than it needs to be because I am
>   slow.

Comment: This is a fairly standard fact. Surely you could check it in Dummit and Foote or any intro to algebra text.

Comment: @3-in-441, it is stated without proof on page 246 on Dummit.

Comment: My apologies then. To be honest I'm not sure what half of your notation means. If you cleaned it up and defined everything you might get a better response. (I'd still wager it's in some algebra text.)

Comment: Are you trying to prove the fourth isomorphism theorem for rings?

Comment: @Xammm, eventually but this part is more important.

Comment: I can figure out the fourth iso once I get this one.

Comment: Are you sure about ideals $I´/I$ of $R$? I think it should be of $R/I$.

Comment: @Xammm, yes u are right, just a typo, but my proof accounted for that.